# Listview item not refreshed correctly when changing Configuration ( Rotating phone)

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that has datasource getting from Network ( quite big list).
What I'm doing is provide 2 different layout for listview item ( just move some label on that list to take advantage of width of view in landscape mode).
I don't want my activity to be reloaded when I rotate my phone, so I set in Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Next, I also implement the override method onConfigurationChanged() in my Activity to help me renew my ListAdapter with new listview item ( for landscape mode ) if it's in Landscape  (by checking newConfiguration.orientation).
I make this listadapter, call notifyDataSetChanged() and also call listview.invalidate() to re-paint the whole listview.
What I get was a big surprise: Some item are changed to new listview item( in landscape mode ) and some other listview item are not changed.

I have spent a lot of time for this and have no clue for this, please help ! 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you please check that where you are calling notifyDataSetChanged(). This may happen that after calling this you are changing your data of listview.

Comment: Actually, this  call may not be neccessay. Because I have create a new adapter with old data and new listitem but I did call it right after I set list adapter.

Comment: please post the code, so that we can understand what's happening, because sometimes same ArrayList(Collection) is used, and one is adapter is removing items from it and other one is adding it again.

Comment: Sorry @AdeelPervaiz , I'm working for a private company :) they had a so-called NON-DISCLOSURE-AGREEMENT .
What I can say is my listview is normal, and it's datasource is a ArrayList, my ListAdapter is customized from ArrayListAdapter , that's all I can say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try doing whatever you are doing inside onConfigurationChanged() through a handler ?

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,500);
}   

Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
        if(msg.what == 1) {
            // do your onConfigurationChanged Stuff
        }
    }
  };
```

Here I'm guessing that you might have to wait for sometime after onConfigurationChanged to update your ListView

Comment: yeah. I'll try this. But I actually call re-paint method ( listview.invalidate() from UI Thread), so I think it's not problem of threading.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Verma, I did it. First time I used that button ;) thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

`android:configChanges="orientation"` is very often NOT the way to go, and as I see it, that's also true for your case.

One very simple fix I did on a when I encountered a similar problem was to return your listview's data in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and use that by calling `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to repopulate your list in onCreate. You can do a null check (and an additional instanceOf to be safe) to fork your logic between loading the data from somewhere, or just casting getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to your listview's data variable.

sample code from my onCreate:

```
if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() == null) {
  catalogUpdater.start(); // start background task of populating your list's contents variable, in my case tempItems
} else {
  tempItems = (ArrayList<WatchListItem>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
  watchListAdapter = new WatchListItemBaseAdapter(MyActivity.this, tempItems);
...
```

Comment: I appreciate your idea, but in my case it's not just the problem of saving data for listview, it's also problem of establishing connection to server and initializing background services. These are expensive actions, both for time and networking. So I choose the way not to let my activity to be reloaded.

Comment: another way maybe to create your own Object that can hold everything you need to save on device rotation (listview items, http objects or whatever) and proceed similarly. background services aren't restarted on device rotation if you implement it correctly, so you just need to reattach values to your variables. i don't know if it's easier or harder for you, but that's supposedly the recommended way of doing things, at least according to most of what I've read. good luck :)